# Resources for WebDriverJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I understand there are the following resources:
http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs

But I was wondering if there was a site that had the entire API of WebDriverJs. Where can I find out what methods are available to me and specific parameters to send in?

Something similar to: http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/frames

Answer (score 2):

There is some good auto-generated description of API methods here:

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/javascript/webdriver/webdriver.js

Answer (score 1):

I was working on a WebDriverJS project recently and got a lot of mileage out of the [Javascript API docs](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/namespace_webdriver.html) page. It's quite easy to navigate, and the code is only a click away. It just looks like the JSDocified version of the [source](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/javascript/webdriver/webdriver.js) on Google Code, but it's much nicer to read and navigate.

Answer (score 1):

WebdriverJS API Documentation  http://webdriver.io/docs.html

Comment: Please note this is not the same project that the question is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

This is the main API documentation for the official Selenium WebDriverJS implementation:

- http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/index.html

You may be mainly interested in:

- [WebDriver](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_WebDriver.html) and
- [WebElement](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_WebElement.html).

---

Please note there used to be two projects named WebDriverJS:

- the official Selenium WebDriverJS, that the question is referring to. (npm module `selenium-webdriver`)
- and the [WebDriverIO](http://webdriver.io/), which some answers are pointing to. (npm module `webdriverio >= 2.x` and `webdriverjs <= 1.7.5`)